# How can I find the uncertainty of derivatives?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, confidence-interval, error-propagation

Suppose I have a quadratic (weighted) least-square fit result obtained from a given set of data:

$$
f(x) = \underbrace{-0.243(\pm0.3324)}_{\text{quad}_a}x^2\underbrace{{}-0.921(\pm0.061)}_{\text{quad}_b}x \underbrace{{}-2.12(\pm0.0223)}_{\text{quad}_c}
$$
If I'm taking the derivative of $f(x)$ to have $f'(x) = Ax+B$, I wonder how can I figure out the uncertainties on $A$ and $B$? I also have the correlations

```
C(quad_a, quad_c) = -0.422
C(quad_a, quad_b) = -0.278
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think that since $f(x) = \alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma$ and so $f'(x) = 2 \alpha x + \beta$ but you have that  $P(−0.243-0.3324 < \alpha < −0.243+0.3324) = 1 - k$ where $1-k$ is your confidence level but then $P(2(−0.243-0.3324) < 2\alpha < 2(−0.243+0.3324)) = 1-k$ while $\beta$ and its error stay the same but I'm not totally sure I have to say

Comment: It seems a bit strange that you have those correlations but you don't have standard errors. $\qquad$